# Married Couples Performing Penance

Tags: krishna

Can you explain the concept of married couples performing penance for 1000 years?

In beginning of Shri Krishna, we are shown that Deviki and Vasudeva perform penance together for 1000 years, see Lord Krishna's form.

Deviki is given the boon of being Lord Krishna's mother in three births.

Now, I am watching the story Yashoda and Nanda, how in previous life they were Dhara and Drona and performed penance for 1000 years to see Lord Krishna in child form.

Here is [Link to Video](https://youtu.be/VplmN2EIMHY?t=8m59s)

Did Husband and Wife do penance for 1000 years together in Ancient India? And is it really 1000 human years?

Please clarify.

Comment: 1000 years penance is not a big thing. There are various examples of penance upto tens of thousands and millions of years... But I think it is as per concenteration level... for eg.. In Adhyatma Ramayana: Ravana, Kumbhakarna, and Vibhisana start and finish penance same time... But Ravana penance was 10000 yrs. And Kumbhakarna and Vibhisana penance was 5000 yrs... So I think it depends on concentration level...

Comment: Drona? is it someone else or the same Dronacharya Martial Arts and Spritiual teacher of Royal Prince of Kuru Dynasty?

Comment: the lifespan of humans decreases as time passes by. In previous yugas, they could live upto 100, 1000 or 10000 years. so yes, it is human years.

Comment: @Yogi, it's someone else. Please refer to video link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VplmN2EIMHY&feature=youtu.be&t=8m59s

Comment: It is about belief and belief systems.And each human has the free choice of believing or not believing.In the extant Youtube video,Penance is performed in a very divine place in the Himalayas.Many believe that there are yogis there doing penances, even today, for lifespans, beyond human comprehension.